# Оптимизация с помощью ссылок

Tags: c++

```
    int arr[3]{45,12,64};

    for (const auto& perf : arr) {
        std::cout << perf << "\t";
    }
```

почему это считается оптимизированней нежели это:

```
    int arr[3]{45,12,64};

    for (auto perf : arr) {
        std::cout << perf << "\t";
    }
```

во втором случае переменная perf инициализируется элементами массива, в первом создается ссылка на элементы массива

Ссылка же тоже занимает место в памяти (не уверен) как и переменная то в чём разница с точки зрение производительности?

Comment: Кем считается? Обычно так считается для каких-то толстых (или неизвестных) классов, а для инта - вряд ли. Подозреваю, что здесь оба варианта соптимизирируются в одно и то же.

Comment: я правильно понимаю если ссылка под капотом это указатель, (вес указателя зависит от архитектуры), то ссылка может весит или 4 байта или 8

Comment: оба варианта переменных имеют класс хранения значения автоматическими, а это значит, что компилятор может хранить эти значения в любом месте. В вашем простом примере никакого места для хранения значения этих переменных не будет вообще.

Comment: Это называется "экономия на спичках". Как говаривал товарищ Кнут, "Корень всех бед в преждевременной оптимизации". Неоднократно встречающийся тип вопросов — применяют очень плохой алгоритм, а потом пытаются выяснить, как его ускорить вот такими вот ухищрениями...

Answer (score 2):

При таком маленьком размере разницы нет, особенно при оптимизации: https://godbolt.org/z/b1KoWKPez

Как видите, код совершенно одинаков.

```
main:
        push    r12
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+8], 64
        mov     rbx, rsp
        lea     r12, [rsp+12]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp], rax
        mov     rbp, rbx
.L2:
        mov     esi, DWORD PTR [rbp+0]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        add     rbp, 4
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     edx, 1
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        cmp     rbp, r12
        jne     .L2
.L3:
        mov     esi, DWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        add     rbx, 4
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     edx, 1
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        cmp     rbx, r12
        jne     .L3
```